# How to handle hardware back button key of Android using AngularJS route

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, back-button

I have to handle hardware back key of android using Angular / Cordova. I have the following code:

```css
 if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.includes('login')) {
            console.log("3$rootScope.disableBackPress.." + $rootScope.disableBackPress);
            navigator.app.exitApp();
} else if ($rootScope.disableBackPress === 1) {
    // Code to go home - prevent navigation drawer going back
    ??
} else {
    // Always goes to home instead of -1 
    // navigator.app.backHistory();
    console.log("2$rootScope.disableBackPress.." + $rootScope.disableBackPress);
    // Always goes to home instead of -1
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```